# Show overlay on image on mobile devices using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch-event

I have a requirement where I need to show overlay on image on mobile devices whenever user touches the image. I am doing it with the code shown below:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
    
    let elementExists = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
    let Center = document.createElement('div');

     
    if (!elementExists) {
      let Wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      let parentElement = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
      Wrapper.classList.add('Wrapper');
      Wrapper.id = 'wrapper';
      
     Center.classList.add('Center');
      
     parentElement.appendChild(Wrapper);
     Wrapper.appendChild(Center);
    
      Wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', function(event){
        if (document.getElementById('wrapper')) {
            document.getElementById('wrapper').remove();
        }
      });
    }
});
```

```css
.col-md-6 {
        width: 375px;
        height: 211px;
        margin: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
        .Wrapper {
        display: table;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1000;
        font-family: arial;
        color: #fff;
        top: 0;
    }

    .Center {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="https://google.com">
<img src="https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" />
</a>
</div>
```

The above code works fine, but I have image wrapped in `a` tag so by default it showing me screen when user touches an image as shown below:

[image]

And because of it overlay is not displaying on mobile screen. I would require help how can I fix it.

**EDIT:**

I am thinking of adding touch swipe event using plain JavaScript but I am not able to do it exactly.
Please let me know if I can get any help!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just leave out the link and just add the event listener directly to the image?

Comment: I am adding event listener to image only. Not to link.

Comment: So you're actually trying to have the image be both a link and have an on touch event?

Comment: What he means is that you can just do everything from JS since you have the mouse events anyway, and by doing so you can get rid of the anchor tags.

Comment: I not getting exactly. But I need both the behavior on image. 1. If user clicks on image it should redirect him to a href link. 2. If user long touch that image it should show overlay without showing popup. Please let me know possible solution.

Comment: @BojanIvanac Yes, my requirement is to treat image both as link and has touch event.

Comment: I think you will have to choose between one or the other. Possibly there is a solution to this, but it would just be a whole lot of coding because of a really bad UX decision. If this is your project, I would come up with some other way to solve this. That's just my personal opinion though.

Comment: @BojanIvanac I am open to suggestions, Yes I know its really bad as UX design.. what I am thinking is having something like long touch event but it seems pure JS doesn't have any such event

Comment: Maybe you can add a icon to the corner of the image that would work as your anchor tag, and have the other functionality when the user touches anywhere else except the icon?

Comment: Yup great we can! but I don't want to change html, I want to do this only with html.

Comment: You wouldn't need to change the layout, you would just need to add a single favicon into the image, and position it into the corner with css, give it a z-index and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Native behaviour for links on mobile devices works as you explained. It will trigger menu when holding. If you don't need link just remove it like Bojan said.

Comment: I not getting exactly. But I need both the behavior on image. 1. If user clicks on image it should redirect him to a href link. 2. If user long touch that image it should show overlay without showing popup. Please let me know possible solution.